# Spring Roo Database Reverse Engineer DBO?

Tags: java, database, reverse-engineering, spring-roo

I'm reverse engineering a Database in Spring Roo. The commands database reverse engineer --schema no-schema-required (all that the roo shell presents me with) and database introspect --schema no-schema-required both return the message

**Schema(s) 'no-schema-required' do not exist or does not have any tables. Note that the schema names of some databases are case-sensitive**

But when I run database reverse engineer --schema dbo or database introspect --schema dbo I get the expected results. What does DBO stand for / do in this instance?

Answer (score 3):

dbo would be your schema name. No-schema-required is presented for the databases which do not support schema

see http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/base-dbre.html